# Метод add и Arrays.asList, альтернатива?

Tags: java, arraylist

У меня есть метод `add()`:

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
fruits.add("Apple");
fruits.add("Banana");
fruits.add("Lemon");
```

и есть вот такой вариант (увидел в книге):

```
 List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Lemon");
```

Одинаковы они? Это похоже на массив который заполняем `= {"Apple", "Banana"};` и **когда мы присваиваем индексу какое-нибудь значение**, правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как указано в документации [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray. The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess. This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size list initialized to contain several elements.

Используя этот метод, мы можем преобразовать массив в `List` фиксированного размера. Этот `List` - просто оболочка, которая делает массив доступным в виде списка. Никакие данные не копируются и не создаются.

Кроме того, мы не можем изменить его длину, потому что добавление или удаление элементов запрещено, при попытке выполнить операции `add`, `remove` вылетит `UnsupportedOperationException`.
Однако мы можем изменять отдельные элементы внутри массива.

И еще такой нюанс, все изменения, которые мы вносим в отдельные элементы `List`'a, будут отражены в нашем исходном массиве, например:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
List stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
stringList.set(0, "E");
```

При попытке вывести оба списка в консоль, получим:

```
[E, B, C, D]
[E, B, C, D]
```

Как видите, наш исходный массив тоже был изменен. И `List`, и массив теперь содержат одни и те же элементы в одном порядке.

Answer (score 0):

По большому счету то же, только во втором случае создается лист с фиксированным размером, тое добавить в него дополнительный элемент не удастся.

Answer (score 0):

Верный ответ уже дан, но внесу свою маленькую капельку.
Чтобы избежать множества строк типа `list.add()` и при этом получить "нормальный", т.е. расширяемый лист можно написать `List<String> strList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));`